# android WebView how to remove white bar at top

Tags: android, xml, webview

At the top of my android WebView there is a white bar it is inside the WebView do you have any ideas how to remove it? Thankyou :)

`<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="-7dip"/>`

Comment: post a screenshot of it

Comment: Need 10 reputation to post images -_- I can email it if you want the witebar is inside the webview at the top

Comment: you can post image link

Comment: Where do I upload the image to link it?

Comment: tried other website? Looks like website's fault.

Comment: Its not other peoples blog apps for the same website have no white bar at top :/

Comment: try `layout_marginTop="-5dp"` or some more

Comment: Will when I've finished my tea XD this gravy is orgasmic